# Can't add symbols to ../../lib/libLLVMSupport.a when building llvm-6.0.0 using llvm-5.0

Tags: compiling, cmake, llvm

Here is the information about my system and the compiler I use:

```
Linux version 4.9.0-5-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 
6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-1
8) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04)

clang version 5.0.1-svn325091-1~exp1 (branches/release_50)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

I have problem with building llvm-6.0.0 with libcxx. I downloaded all of them from [llvm download page](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) and put the source code like there:

```
llvm-6.0
  build
  llvm-6.0.0
    ...(other stuff)
    tools
      clang
    projects
      libcxx 
      libcxxabi
```

And here is the command I used:

```
#!/bin/bash
#References: https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html
cd build
#The option for llvm starts from line 5, for libcxx starts from line 15
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release                  \
      -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-5.0                \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-5.0            \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/          \
      -DLLVM_INSTALL_BINUTILS_SYMLINKS=True       \
      -DLLVM_INSTALL_CCTOOLS_SYMLINKS=True        \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_CXX1Y=True                    \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=True                       \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=True                     \
      -DLLVM_ENABLE_LTO=Thin                      \
      -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=False            \
      -DLIBCXX_INSTALL_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=True  \
      -DLIBCXX_LIBDIR_SUFFIX=/usr/local/lib       \
      -DLIBCXX_BENCHMARK_NATIVE_STDLIB="libstdc++"\
      -G Unix Makefiles                           \
      ..
cmake --build .
```

The cmake gives:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Demangle/CMakeFiles/LLVMDemangle.dir/ItaniumDemangle.cpp.o
[  0%] Linking CXX static library ../libLLVMDemangle.a
[  0%] Built target LLVMDemangle
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/AMDGPUMetadata.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APFloat.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APInt.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APSInt.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMAttributeParser.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMWinEH.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Allocator.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BinaryStreamError.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BinaryStreamReader.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BinaryStreamRef.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BinaryStreamWriter.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BlockFrequency.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BranchProbability.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/circular_raw_ostream.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/COM.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CodeGenCoverage.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CommandLine.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Compression.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ConvertUTF.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ConvertUTFWrapper.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CrashRecoveryContext.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DataExtractor.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Debug.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DebugCounter.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DeltaAlgorithm.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DAGDeltaAlgorithm.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Error.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ErrorHandling.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/FileUtilities.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/FileOutputBuffer.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/FoldingSet.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/FormattedStream.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/FormatVariadic.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/GlobPattern.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/GraphWriter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Hashing.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/IntEqClasses.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/IntervalMap.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/JamCRC.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/KnownBits.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/LEB128.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/LineIterator.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Locale.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/LockFileManager.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/LowLevelType.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ManagedStatic.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/MathExtras.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/MemoryBuffer.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/MD5.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/NativeFormatting.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Options.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Parallel.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/PluginLoader.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/PrettyStackTrace.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/RandomNumberGenerator.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Regex.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ScaledNumber.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ScopedPrinter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/SHA1.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/SmallPtrSet.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/SmallVector.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/SourceMgr.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/SpecialCaseList.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Statistic.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/StringExtras.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/StringMap.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/StringPool.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/StringSaver.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/StringRef.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/SystemUtils.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/TarWriter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/TargetParser.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ThreadPool.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Timer.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ToolOutputFile.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/TrigramIndex.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Triple.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Twine.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Unicode.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/YAMLParser.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/YAMLTraits.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/raw_os_ostream.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/raw_ostream.cpp.o
[  2%] Building C object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/regcomp.c.o
[  2%] Building C object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/regerror.c.o
[  2%] Building C object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/regexec.c.o
[  2%] Building C object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/regfree.c.o
[  2%] Building C object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/regstrlcpy.c.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/xxhash.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Atomic.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DynamicLibrary.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Errno.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Host.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Memory.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Mutex.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Path.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Process.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Program.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/RWMutex.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Signals.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/TargetRegistry.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ThreadLocal.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Threading.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Valgrind.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Watchdog.cpp.o
[  2%] Linking CXX static library ../libLLVMSupport.a
[  2%] Built target LLVMSupport
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/Error.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/Main.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/Record.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/SetTheory.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/StringMatcher.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/TableGenBackend.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/TGLexer.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object lib/TableGen/CMakeFiles/LLVMTableGen.dir/TGParser.cpp.o
[  2%] Linking CXX static library ../libLLVMTableGen.a
[  2%] Built target LLVMTableGen
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/AsmMatcherEmitter.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/AsmWriterEmitter.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/AsmWriterInst.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/Attributes.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CallingConvEmitter.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeEmitterGen.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenDAGPatterns.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenHwModes.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenInstruction.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenMapTable.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenRegisters.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenSchedule.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CodeGenTarget.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DAGISelEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DAGISelMatcherEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DAGISelMatcherGen.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DAGISelMatcherOpt.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DAGISelMatcher.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DFAPacketizerEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/DisassemblerEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/FastISelEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/FixedLenDecoderEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/GlobalISelEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/InfoByHwMode.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/InstrInfoEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/InstrDocsEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/IntrinsicEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/OptParserEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/PseudoLoweringEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/RegisterBankEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/RegisterInfoEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/SDNodeProperties.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/SearchableTableEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/SubtargetEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/SubtargetFeatureInfo.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/TableGen.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/Types.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86DisassemblerTables.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86EVEX2VEXTablesEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86FoldTablesEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86ModRMFilters.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86RecognizableInstr.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CTagsEmitter.cpp.o
[  4%] Built target obj.llvm-tblgen
[  4%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-tblgen
../../lib/libLLVMSupport.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target 'bin/llvm-tblgen' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/llvm-tblgen] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:906: recipe for target 'utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to fix this problem by:

1. Use  `cmake --build . --target clean` to remove the built files and run `cmake --build .` again.
2. Follow the instruction given above, change directory into lib, and run `ranlib libLLVMSupport.a`.

But none of these worked: I ran `cmake --build .` again, and they gave:

```
[  0%] Built target LLVMDemangle
[  2%] Built target LLVMSupport
[  2%] Built target LLVMTableGen
[  4%] Built target obj.llvm-tblgen
[  4%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-tblgen
../../lib/libLLVMSupport.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; 
run ranlib to add one
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/build.make:158: recipe for 
target 'bin/llvm-tblgen' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/llvm-tblgen] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:906: recipe for target 
'utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/llvm-tblgen.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked the timestamp of lib/libLLVMSupport.a in method 2, and found it was not changed, means it was not regenerated by `cmake --build .`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found out what really caused this error.

The cmake was using gnu golden linker, and the archieve libLLVMSupport.a was composed of LLVM IR code, no wonder it went wrong.

After I switched to using ld.lld-5.0, all errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you leave the archives as separate files? and then link  the application to all the required archive(s).